# GC log nursery value=0

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

Below is my GC log output

```
<mem-info id="93" free="2404193232" total="2518572288" percent="85">
    <mem type="nursery" free="0" total="412653184" percent="0" />
    <mem type="tenure" free="2504193232" total="2515919104" percent="99">
      <mem type="soa" free="2083398096" total="2195123968" percent="99" />
      <mem type="loa" free="130795136" total="130795136" percent="100" />
    </mem>
```

Is mem type="nursery" free="0"  .... concerning ?

If if "nursery" value is concerning, then what JVM argument should i put in to overcome this concern.

Also,

i see copy-failed:

```
 <copy-failed type="nursery" objects="133" bytes="3424" />
  <copy-failed type="tenure" objects="669590" bytes="15098200" />
```

This is a Webspehere JVM.

Many Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Is mem type="nursery" free="0" .... concerning ? yes if its after scavenge gc. you may tune nursery for better performance

-Xmn can be used to increase nursery size